# AWS still showing services in Bills and resource groups in Tag Editor after terminating my EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I terminated my EC2 Instance I saw that I still have services in my **Bills**. I also don't know what the **Data Transfer** and **Key Management Service** is for and how I got billed for these. I terminated my EC2 Instance in the first week of the month do I maybe wait until the end of the month for them to disappear?
[image]

Another thing is that when I tried to stop more resources, I got 140 results in different regions in my tag editor is that normal and do I need to stop all of them to stop getting charged?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As if you still charging for services so firstly check for which service you are charging currently via below steps:

**Step1** - Go to my Billing dashboard from top right of your profile.

**Step2** - Under left pane menu -> Billing -> go to Bills.

Here you can find bills according to month with charges based on different services.

If you click on a specific service(drop down), you can find, under which region the service has been launched and its charges.

After this terminate all your running instances and other services as well.